# Is it possible to replace a file from one repository to another with android repo tool?

Tags: yocto, repo

I'm using [repo tool](https://source.android.com/setup/develop/repo) to build a Yocto project, the repositories used are A, B, yocto ..., and I need to replace a file from A to B, the structure is something like this:

```
A/MyFile.sh

B/TheFile.sh

yocto/Some_dirs_and_files
```

So, I use the copyfile like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
  <remote fetch="mygitrepo" name="origin"/>
  <default remote="origin"/>
  <project name="yocto" revision="myrevision"/>
  <project name="meta-openembedded" path="yocto/meta-openembedded" revision="myrevision"/>
  <project name="B" path="yocto/B" revision="myrevision"/>
  <project name="C" path="yocto/meta-swi-extras" revision="myrevision"/>
  <project name="poky" path="yocto/poky" revision="myrevision"/>
  <project name="A" path="yocto/custom-builds" revision="myrevision">
    <copyfile src="MyFile.sh" dest="yocto/B/TheFile.sh"/>
  </project>
</manifest>
```

The problem is that the **copyfile** is not replacing the file "TheFile.sh" with "MyFile.sh"

Is there a way to do it without an additional script?

Note: If I change the dest name from

```
dest="yocto/B/TheFile.sh
```

to

```
dest="yocto/B/AnotherFile.sh
```

the file is succesfully copied, but if I set the name to the file I want to replace it doesn't.

Comment: It looks like you try to do it in a right way. I [don't see](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/docs/manifest-format.txt) any additional options for `copyfile`. So in my opinion to find the answer you should dive into `repo's` source code.

Comment: Generally i fork repo for this kind of stuff. You can maybe try to use symlinks `linkfile`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems repo do now allow overwrite file by `<copyfile src=.. dest ...>`

From repo [source code `project.py`](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/project.py)

```
 class _CopyFile(object):
 def __init__(self, src, dest, abssrc, absdest):
    self.src = src
    self.dest = dest
    self.abs_src = abssrc
    self.abs_dest = absdest
  def _Copy(self):
    src = self.abs_src
    dest = self.abs_dest
    # copy file if it does not exist or is out of date
    if not os.path.exists(dest) or not filecmp.cmp(src, dest): ※
```

※line shows the condition to do a file copy.

Answer (score 0):

code below your pice

```
if not os.path.exists(dest) or not filecmp.cmp(src, dest):
  try:
    # remove existing file first, since it might be read-only
    if os.path.exists(dest):
      platform_utils.remove(dest)
    else:
      dest_dir = os.path.dirname(dest)
      if not platform_utils.isdir(dest_dir):
        os.makedirs(dest_dir)
    shutil.copy(src, dest)
    # make the file read-only
    mode = os.stat(dest)[stat.ST_MODE]
    mode = mode & ~(stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IWGRP | stat.S_IWOTH)
    os.chmod(dest, mode)
```

so it can replace ...

Answer (score 0):

is this still open?
I just happened to come across the same issue, wanting to overwrite a file from `repository2` with a file from `repository1`, the `<copyfile>` was in place to replace `myfile` from `repository2` with `myfile` from `repository1`. I was using a yocto distribution (with several layers, as git repositories).
But it did not work.
Copying `myfile` from `repository1` as `myfile2` to `repository2` (another name) worked.

What I discovered was that running the repo init/sync commands several times I did not get the repos to be populated in the same order.

So basically my `<copyfile>` did what is was supposed to do when `repository1` was populated, but that happened **before** `repository2` was populated (even if they were in the right order in the manifest file). And `repository2` simply brought its own `myfile`, overwriting the one copied by `repository1`.

My mega-solution was to use two `<copyfile>` tags: one in `repository1` to copy `myfile` as `myfile2` into `repository2`, and the other in `repository2` to copy `myfile2` as `myfile`.

You have to make sure though that `repository1` is always populated before `repository2`.
This all thing is very strange, since repo does not guarantee the order in which repositoruies are populated.